Contrasts from lm in R
I have data where I want to compare the level of a factor with the mean of another level of that factor. In addition, I want to create this contrast for all levels of another factor.
So I want to get a coefficient that gives the difference in means between the key factor level and another level nested within each level of a second factor.
Ideally, I could do this all in R with a single call to lm(). I know how to do this using marginal effects packages or using separate regressions. But is it possible to do within one single lm()?
I would probably need to create a specific covariate to get that effect, right?
I tried the x + x:y model syntax, which works for one interaction. But as soon as another interaction is included in the same model, the estimates diverge. I know why this happens, but I don't know if it is possible to stop it with some clever recoding of factors or contrast coding.
Some example code where I am interested in estimating the mean difference between cyl 8 and 4 within the levels of am:
library(marginaleffects) # For comparisons
data(mtcars)

mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am)

# This doesn't give me marginal effects, obviously.
mod <- lm(mpg ~ cyl * am + gear, data = mtcars)
summary(mod)

# This is what I want to estimate in the model directly:
avg_comparisons(mod,
  variables = "cyl",
  by = "am")

# This is getting me to my desired estimates:
mod2 <- lm(mpg ~ am / cyl + gear, data = mtcars)
summary(mod2)

# For comparison
avg_comparisons(mod2,
  variables = "cyl",
  by = "am")

# However, if I include a second set of interactions with cyl, the estimates diverge from the marginal comparisons:
mod3 <- lm(mpg ~  am / cyl + gear / cyl, data = mtcars)
summary(mod3)

avg_comparisons(mod3,
  variables = "cyl",
  by = "am")

# I don't see a way of fixing the model unfortunately


include by = c("am", "gear") should give you an insight of what you want

My question is more about how to specify the contrasts I want inside the model matrix.

Why are you doing this: mtcars$vs <- factor(mtcars$gear)?

The differences for am0 are given in the coefficients of mod. For am1, you simply add the last two coefficients.

That was a typo, sorry.
Yes, you can simply calculate the marginal effects from the model coefficients. However, I was wondering if you could get the desired comparisons and t-tests directly in the linear regression results. For simple one-factor comparisons, this is trivial but for this example, it seemed more complicated to me.
